# Print all fields from two tables and set some column values to null based on a column using ORACLE CASE statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to print all columns but for some I need to print null using CASE in Oracle

```
| Db fields     | Male    |Female|Trans |
| ------------- | ------- |------|------|
|customer_id    | Y       |      |      |
|customer_name  | Y       |   Y  |  Y   |
|address        |         |   Y  |      |
|city           | Y       |   Y  |  Y   |
|state          | Y       |   Y  |  Y   |
|zip_code       |         |   Y  |      |
|customer_type  | Y       |      |  Y   |
```

PS-This is not a table

**I was trying to write this query** -

```
select
case
     when c.customer_type='Female' then customer_id is null 
     when c.customer_type='Trans' then customer_id is null
case(address)
     when c.customer_type='Male' then address is null 
     when c.customer_type='Trans' then address is null
case(zip_code)
     when c.customer_type='Male' then zip_code is null 
     when c.customer_type='Trans' then zip_code is null
case(customer_type)
    when c.customer_type='Female' then customer_type is null
end
c.customer_id, c.customer_name, c.address, c.city, c.state,c.zip_code,c.customer_type, e.employee_number, e.employee_name from customers c, employees e where e.customer_id=c.customer_id where c.customerid=1;
```

**This is not working**.

============================================================

The tables and columns just for reference:

```
CREATE TABLE customers(
  customer_id number(10) NOT NULL,
  customer_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  address varchar2(50),
  city varchar2(50),
  state varchar2(25),
  zip_code varchar2(10),
  customer_type varchar2(10),
  CONSTRAINT customers_pk PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
);
insert into customers values(1,'A','Japan','Tokyo','J',001,'Male');
insert into customers values(2,'B','UK','London','U',002,'Female');
insert into customers values(3,'C','China','Tibet','S',003,'Trans');
insert into customers values(4,'D','South korea','Souel','S',004,'Female');

CREATE TABLE employees(
  employee_number number(10) NOT NULL,
  employee_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  customer_id number(10),
  CONSTRAINT employees_pk PRIMARY KEY (employee_number),
  CONSTRAINT fk_customers FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers(customer_id));


insert into employees values(101,'titu',1);
insert into employees values(102,'kitu',2);
insert into employees values(103,'pitu',3);
insert into employees values(104,'yitu',4);
```

Comment: Please, do not post the same question twice. You may edit your old question and clarify the problem. [Dynamic Single query for handling multiple columns in then in Oracle case statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68381903/dynamic-single-query-for-handling-multiple-columns-in-then-in-oracle-case-statem)

Comment: *Is this correct. I don't understand how to handle the above query.* - We cannot tell you. If this query runs and gives you what you want, then it is correct. Unless you provide source data and desired output it is still not answerable

Comment: Yes deleted the previous question

Comment: No actually I am asking if we can write CASE statement like this

Comment: It's not working

Comment: `case` in SQL statement is an expression. Expression evaluates to a single scalar value (it may be of complex type, but always a single instance). It does not sets something. So `then customer_id=null` is invalid. If you wanted to set the value to `null` in some cases, then it should be written in another way, which was provided to you in you previous question (which you've deleted for some reason instead of edit). But looks that it is not what you want, so describe your requirements with sample data and desired results

Comment: It's quite hard to explain. I wish I could show. Let me explain : So, in the application or say website I have list of customers with all these columns. Now, suppose I select one customer with custid =1. if this custid has custtype male then all those above will get print and for some columns it will be null. Again if we select custid 3 and this custid has cutstype Female then all columns except some will print null. I was told to write such a query rest the application is smart enough to handle

Comment: Please update your question instead of adding additional information in the comments. I posted an answer based on a comment in your deleted question but I'm not sure it fits based on this latest comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could print the output as a single column that consists of multiple concatenated columns. From your (deleted) previous question you indicated that this is for a label, so you don't need multiple columns. In the code below, different columns are concatenated based on the value of customer_type.

This could work:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN customer_type = 'Male' THEN
      c.customer_id ||' -> '|| c.customer_name ||' -> '|| c.city ||' -> '|| c.state ||' -> '|| c.customer_type  
    WHEN customer_type = 'Female' THEN
      c.customer_name ||' -> '|| c.address ||' -> '|| c.city ||' -> '|| c.state ||' -> '|| c.zip_code  
    WHEN customer_type = 'Trans' THEN
      c.customer_name ||' -> '|| c.city ||' -> '|| c.state ||' -> '|| c.customer_type     
  END as "Output"
  FROM customers c 
       JOIN employees e ON e.customer_id=c.customer_id;


Output                                                                                                                                                                                                   
---------------------------
1 -> A -> Tokyo -> J -> Male
B -> UK -> London -> U -> 2
C -> Tibet -> S -> Trans
D -> South korea -> Souel -> S -> 4
```